# Firebase photoURL is not displaying properly in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm using the Firebase authentication module in react-native with native-cli. On sign up, I'm uploading an image using **react-native-document-picker**. After selecting an image from the gallery it will look like this:

```json
{
  "fileCopyUri":"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A33077",
  "name":"IMG-20211005-WA0007.jpg",
  "size":67094,
  "type":"image/jpeg",
  "uri":"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A33077"
}
```

and using this function to upload it on firebase:

```js
auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
     displayName:fullname,
     photoURL:JSON.stringify(pic),
})
```

now when I get it like this:

```js
const fireUser = auth().currentUser;
console.log(JSON.parse(fireUser.photoURL))
```

It displays the image on the screen but when I quit the app and again open or log in to the app it's not displaying the image but I'm having pic in photoURL.

Is it possible to convert file?

```json
{
  "fileCopyUri":"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A33077",
  "name":"IMG-20211005-WA0007.jpg",
  "size":67094,
  "type":"image/jpeg",
  "uri":"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A33077"
}
```

into URL?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're passing to `updateProfile` is a local URL on your Android device, which won't work. To ensure the profile is visible, upload the local file to a public place in the cloud, and then pass the URL for that location to `updateProfile`.

For example, you can [upload the file to Cloud Storage with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file), then [get the download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) that provides read-only, public access to it, and store that in the user profile.

Comment: ok I check that but how I can link that specific image related to this user?

Comment: You can use the user's UID for example to determine the path of the file that you upload the image to. That way you can also secure the upload, so that users can only upload their own profile picture as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#cloud-storage_2

Comment: Any update here @AdilIjaz?

Comment: thank you. but i shifted to django blackend